# Audio doesn't play in SSML if action is activated by keyboard

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to play an audio file in the SSML using a code like this :

```
conv.ask(`<speak>playing sound
            <break time="300ms"/>
            <audio src="sound.mp3"/>
          </speak>`);
```

it works  fine on the iPhone using google assistant if the action is invoked by voice and it plays back the audio, however if I activate the action by typing the action name on keyboard(talk to .....), only the display text is shown and no audio is played back. I am doing something wrong? is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Can you update your question to elaborate on what device you're seeing this behavior? OR any other details about what you're doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out that is the intended behaviour of AoG. If the action is invoked by keyboard, only the text part of the response is displayed and the "audio" tag inside the SSML is ignored. I had to change my response to include a [MediaObject](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses) and it is now playing the audio regardless of if it is invoked by voice or keyboard.